# C# HttpRequest - Accessing hashtags in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, httprequest, code-behind, hashtag

Unfortunately because of the wide use of the word "hashtag" and "httprequest" i couldn't find any search results that gave me an answer on whether something like this is even possible.

If i have a url like this:

> /Orders/Product#12345

The HttpRequest class shows me that the FilePath, RawUrl, and all other members that show the url as

> /Orders/Product

It just gets rid of the hashtag, and i can't find a place to view it.

Is there any way for me to be able to see what hashtag is at the end of the URL from the codebehind? I know i could easily make this a QueryString parameter, but i like the way this looks better, so if there's a way to do it, i'd like to find out what it is :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Others have answered the question well. I thought it might be helpful to know that the part of the URL after (and including) the # mark is called the fragment.

Answer (score 11):

> It just gets rid of the hashtag, and i can't find a place to view it.

That's because it doesn't get sent to the server. It's not part of the request - it's *only* relevant on the client side. If you need to do anything clever with it, you'll need to write some Javascript to access it.

Comment: That's what i needed to know! Guess i'll go with `"/Orders/Product/12345"` since my MVC routing allows that to go to the same page while keeping the end in tact :)

Thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Browser is not required to do GET request in case of navigation to bookmarks on the same page (what #12345 is). So you may reconsider using it for normal requests.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated this value is not sent to the server. While it's possible to send the value to the server using JavaScript, in this instance you should make it a query string parameter.

Comment: I was trying to avoid going QueryString from my petty preference of not wanting to decide on a variable name for the parameter :P 

Going with `/Orders/Product/12345` instead, Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in a view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("JavascriptPlugins", "Docs")#typeahead">Typeahead</a>
```