# django-registration and redirect containing hashtag

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm using django-registration to handle login and user registration in my Django app. I'd like the user to get redirected to the url they requested after they have successfully logged on to the system (assuming they were logged off when they tried to access the url initially).

The login url looks like:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/#foo/bar/
```

However, after the login, the user always ends up at `http://localhost:8000/`. I've tried it with `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/abc/def/` and that worked fine, so I assume the hashtag is the problem. How can this be fixed (if at all)?

### Update

I should have mentioned that it's a single page app, hence the hashtag...

Comment: What are you trying to do? The hashtag is designed to refer to a specific part of the page. Why would http://localhost:8000/#foo/bar/ make sense?

Comment: It's a single page app. I'd like to redirect the user to the last visited page.

Comment: I've been trying to find the code which parses the "next" parameter, but it doesn't look like django-registration or Django core's code does it? Sorry if I'm not being helpful.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it anyway. I seems odd that this doesn't work. A simple (forced) `redirect('#foo/bar/')` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started stepping through the  django-registration (actually django) code. I couldn't find anything django-registration is doing during the login, so I think it isn't even responsible for this part.

Django wraps `@login_required` view functions in `_wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs)` functions (`django.contrib.auth.decorators`) and performs an authentication test before executing the actual function. If found not logged in yet, it gets the current url as `next` (`path = request.build_absolute_uri()`) and starts the login. However, `request.build_absolute_uri()` doesn't even return the hashtag url. Extracting the #-appended part of the url does generally not seem to be [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110901/c-sharp-httprequest-accessing-hashtags-in-url).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the necromancer, but I solved this issue with the following:

I have a template for the login form with the following:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_next" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
    ... the actual form here ...
</form>
```

and (I am using JQuery) the following script at the end:

```
<script>$(function () { 
    $("#hidden_next").attr(
        "value", "{{ next }}" + 
            $(location).attr('hash'))
    });
</script>
```

Note that I am repeating the `{{ next }}` just in case the user disables Javascript. In a single page app this is not an issue, as a user disabling javascript cannot use the page at all.